# Compare docker images in Azure cluster

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, daemonset

I recently switched from AWS to Azure and i'm having issues with getting the docker to run in my daemonset.

On AWS I was pulling an image of a Pod and doing docker diff to compare that image with the original one.

But on Azure now i cannot access the docker and can't seem to find a way to get the original image and the current image with changes of the pod.

How can i do something like docker diff or at least pickup the two images in Azure ?

Comment: Is this in Kubernetes/AKS?  You can't normally directly access the host and there isn't guaranteed to be a Docker daemon.  If you specify `image:` in your pod spec and the image isn't already on the node then Kubernetes will pull it for you.  What workflow leads you to want to compare different images?

Comment: When i terminate a Pod i want to take its image and compare the changes that are done. I need the differences between the original and the used image for some statistics regarding the pod usage. It is in AKS yes, deployed via helm, nothing unusual just regular daemonset with pods & services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Kubernetes are you running in AKS?  Kubernetes has deprecated Docker as a container runtime after v1.20 so you can't run DOCKER DIFF on a node anymore.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/

Comment: Yes you are right, i am using 1.20 so that is what was causing my troubles. So there is no way i can actually do this on newer kubernetes versions ?

Comment: You can try installing the CRICTL CLI tool but it seems that DIFF is not implemented: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/.  CRICTL doc: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md